# Multithreaded Java console app gradually slower on one server

Tags: java, multithreading, console

I have a multithreaded Java app that does the following:

1. Iterate all files in a folder recursively in the main thread.
2. Launch a new Thread (`Runnable` impl) for every file

   1. The thread checks if a file has been *transformed* yet. (transform = copy + add extension + generate metadatafile)
   2. If yes, it is skipped and the thread ends.  If not, the file is *transformed* after which the thread ends.

I have used this app on many machines and servers, with different max threads (4-8-10-25) and it has always run very smoothly and fast except on our newest server.

Server Info:

- OS: Win2012 64bit, HyperV VM
- Java: JDK 1.7.0_80 64bit

On this particular server the application starts off fast and gradually slows down after a couple of minutes.  Example: it normally takes 15ms on average to process documents (combined over the threads), now it takes over a second after 30mins to transforma  document, or even to skip a document.

I have used task manager and JVisualVM to check what's happening but I can't pinpoint the problem.

Observations:

- CPU not nearly on 100% on any of the virtual cores
- RAM only used 50%
- disk I/O seems ok as well
- McAfee is not scanning every document (we checked)
- Java is started with `-Xms1024m -Xmx3072m` and only 500MB of the initial memory is used
- PermGen is OK
- Manually Garbage Collecting from JVisualVM is not doing anything to increase the speed.
- Restarting the app immediately makes it go fast again but it just slows down again after a couple of minutes.
- I see that all my threads are almost always in 'Park' state in JVisualVM.  i don't know if this is normal or not.
- We tried adding `LockSupport.unpark(Thread.currentThread())` in a finally block inside the thread class but that does nothing.

Code snippets:

Launching threads for each file:

```
ThreadCountAwareThreadFactory threadFactory = ThreadCountAwareThreadFactory.getThreadFactory();
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(getMaxThreads(), threadFactory);

//iterate files here and for each file do the following
for(...) {
    ContentProvider contentProvider = springHelper.getBean(ContentProvider.class);          
    MetadataProvider metadataProvider = springHelper.getBean(MetadataProvider.class);
    ScopeSelector scopeSelector = springHelper.getBean(ScopeSelector.class);

    ThreadDataPackage dpkg = dataPackagesIterator.next();
    executor.execute(new TransformThread(dpkg, contentProvider, metadataProvider, scopeSelector, file, getOutputDir()));
}

//after all files have a thread launched
try {
    executor.shutdown();

    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    log.info(String.format("All threads (%s) completed...", threadFactory.getSpawnedThreadCount()));
} catch(InterruptedException ie) {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occurred when waiting for threads to complete...", ie);
}
```

TransformThread class (extends `BaseThread` which is just an abstract class with a setter/getter for the thread package):

```
    public class TransformThread extends BaseThread {

    private File file; 
    private Logger log;
    private ContentProvider contentProvider;
    private MetadataProvider metadataProvider;
    private ScopeSelector scopeSelector;
    private String outputDir;
    private String identifier;

    public TransformThread(ThreadDataPackage dataPackage, ContentProvider contentProvider, 
        MetadataProvider metadataProvider, ScopeSelector scopeSelector, File file, String outputDir) {
        super(dataPackage);
        this.contentProvider = contentProvider;
        this.metadataProvider = metadataProvider;
        this.file = file;
        this.log = dataPackage.getLog();
        this.outputDir = outputDir;
        this.scopeSelector = scopeSelector;
        this.identifier = "TransformThread" + hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
            logInfo(">>>> Processing file " + file.getAbsolutePath(), null);

            //check if already processed
            if(isAlreadyProcessed(file)) {
                logInfo(">>>> File was already processed, skipping...", null);
                return;
            }

            contentProvider.setFilePath(file.getAbsolutePath());

            //process metadata
            logInfo(">>>> Processing metadata", null);

            //do some metadata processing and copy the file to the output directory, change extension, etc...

        } catch(Exception e) {
            logSevere("Error occurred during transform", e);
        Transform.addFailedFile(String.format("%s (%s)", file.getAbsolutePath(), e.getMessage()));
        } finally {
            LockSupport.unpark(Thread.currentThread());
        }
    }

    private void logInfo(String msg, Throwable error) {
        doLog(Level.INFO, msg, this.identifier, error);
    }

    private void logSevere(String msg, Throwable error) {
        doLog(Level.SEVERE, msg, this.identifier, error);
    }

    private void doLog(Level lvl, String msg, String identifier, Throwable error) {
        log.log(lvl, identifier + " - " + msg, error);
    }

    private boolean isAlreadyProcessed(File file) {
        return new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + Constants.PROCESSED_MARKER).exists();
    }

    protected void markProcessed(File file) 
            throws IOException {
        File processedMarker = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + Constants.PROCESSED_MARKER);
        processedMarker.createNewFile();
    }

}
```

Does anybody have any idea what's causing the slowness on that server?

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was Java 1.7.  We saw that the common thing all the other servers gad was Java 1.6.0_45 and the new one had 1.7.0_80.

We tried with 1.6 and everything goes perfectly smooth and fast.

I do not know what might have changed between 6 & 7 that would cause this, and I can't find any information in my research. All I know is that downgrading the version worked to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't have any enlightenment, but it might be worth trying 1.8... 1.7 is already getting gray.